# Definition of literal (Java)

Tags: java, literals

According to the JLS 3.10 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/jls12.pdf

> A literal is the source code representation of a value of a primitive
>   type (§4.2), the String type (§4.3.3), or the null type (§4.1).

What about Class object literals? or array literals? etc

Comment: They're not the same. [§15.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8) makes a clear distinction between lexical literals and class literals. And there's no formal concept of array literals.

Comment: @shmosel can you expand on what you mean when you say there is no formal concept of array literals?

Comment: It's not a thing. There's no such term in the JLS.

Comment: @shmosel ah so would you consider it a misnomer? since it seems to be a special feature in java for arrays

Comment: It's just a special type of expression. You can call it a literal if you want, I won't be offended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not the same. [§15.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8) makes a clear distinction between lexical literals and class literals. And there's no formal concept of array literals.